# Matlab getting point coordinates

Tags: matlab, function, plot

How can I get the coordinates at a specific point?

I want to get the X coordinate of the points with `Y = 18.1` ; `Y = 33`; `Y = 70`
Those points need to lie on the function that I plot.

Sample Code

```
t = [0  5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60  65  70  75  80  85  90  95  100 105 110 115 120 125 130 135 140 145 150 155 160 165 170 175 180];
y = [0  5   9   19  25  32  46  65  79  90  100 115 123 141 153 159 160 171 181 185 193 200 205 211 215 220 223 222 225 224 228 231 231 228 235 234 231];
plot(t,y) , grid on
```

Comment: What do you mean by "points need to lie on the function"? How can you be sure that they do? Do you want to return a fault if the function plotted does not cross the points you are talking about?

Comment: If you plot the values given, the plot function will do a linear interpolation between your data points. Starting from there, you have to decide if that is what you want and how to handle the cases where multiple solutions exist. Apart from that, `interp1` should do what you want...

Comment: Your function is apparently not monotonic, and therefore not invertible. For certain `Y` values there may be two or more corresponding `X` values. In that case, which `X` value do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are trying to find the values of `t` associated with a `y`, and your function is not monotonic so we need to actually code up a mock linear interpolation. Note, there may be a better way, but I do not know of it right now. Try the following code where `yVals` are the values you want an associated `t` for, and `possArray` will include all values of `t` that may satisfy those conditions.

```
clc; close all; clear all;
t = [0  5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60  65  70  75  80  85  90  95  100 105 110 115 120 125 130 135 140 145 150 155 160 165 170 175 180];
y = [0  5   9   19  25  32  46  65  79  90  100 115 123 141 153 159 160 171 181 185 193 200 205 211 215 220 223 222 225 224 228 231 231 228 235 234 231];
plot(t,y)
grid on
hold on
yVals = [18.1,33,70,222.5,230];
possArray = cell(1,numel(yVals));
iter = 1;
for val = yVals;
    poss = [];
    possNum = 1;
    for i = 1:numel(y)-1
        if y(i) <= val && y(i+1) >= val
            minDiff = val-y(i);
            yDiff = y(i+1)-y(i);
            percAlong = minDiff/yDiff;
            poss(possNum) = (t(i+1)-t(i))*percAlong+t(i);    
            possNum = possNum+1;
        end
    end
    possArray{iter} = poss;
    iter = iter + 1;
end    

colors = hsv(numel(yVals));
legendCell = cell(numel(yVals)+1,1);
legendCell{1} = 'Original Line';
for i = 1:numel(yVals)
    plot(possArray{i},yVals(i)*ones(size(possArray{i})),...
        'x','MarkerSize',10,'LineWidth',2,'Color',colors(i,:))
    legendCell{i+1} = ['Values for Y = ' ,num2str(yVals(i))];
end
legend(legendCell)
hold off
```

As stated previously, this is linear interpolation, so if you need it to be more complicated that is on you, the concept should however be similar

**UPDATE**

Updated code above to be a little more clean, and added a plot indicating that multiple possibilities may arise for a single value, and that the code will return all possibilities.

Comment: @MarianZlatev No problem. Please do take the time to understand how it works. Whether it is a homework problem or not, it is always a good idea to analyze these sorts of things so that you are more well equipped later and can come up with some creative solutions for future problems